# How to add Add frontend product url column to admin product grid

Tags: magento-1.9, product-grid

I want to add new column in the product grid in magento admin to show the frontend product url .

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
```

and add another column

in _prepareCollection
add line

```
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
```

And in _prepareColumns

```
$this->addColumn('url_key',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Url'),
            'index' => 'url_key',
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks Martins 
Its work perfectly :)